# Changing Stripe param keys for mass assignment in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm integrating Stripe into a Rails app. Right now Stripe Checkout returns a params hash with key-value pairs like:

```
"stripeShippingAddressZip"=>"80205"
```

and

```
"stripeShippingAddressState"=>"CO"
```

I also have a method called `order_params` which calls `params.permit` to prevent mass assignment vulnerabilities.

I'd like to do the following:

`current_user.orders.build(order_params)`

Essentially mass assignment.

However, my `orders` model has attributes like `shipping_zip` rather than `stripeShippingAddressZip`.

How can I use the params hash and still do mass assignment given that the hash keys don't match the attributes of the model?

Is there are "Rails way" of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this, but I like to do the mapping like so:

```
def order_params
  {
    shipping_zip: params[:stripeShippingAddressZip],
    # more here
  }
end
```

After this you can just do:

```
Orders.create(order_params)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Would you add this in the same method as params.permit? Or as an alternative to params.permit?

Comment: This is a way of permit. Permit is used when the names being sent as the response is correct and we just need to allow them. Here we have to allow and rename. So this works as an alternative.

Comment: @jessesr you can accept the answer if it solves your problem!